# How do I delegate from one Scene another in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit, delegates

I need some help setting up delegation in SpriteKit. the function in second scene is not called.
But I just cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Many thanks in advance

```
protocol receivingStringDelegate:class {

    func didReceiveString(message:String)
}

class GameScene: SKScene  {

    weak var gamescene_transmissiondelegate: receivingStringDelegate?

    private func sendString(message:String){

        gamescene_transmissiondelegate?. didReceiveString(message)

    }
}


class SecondScene: SKScene, receivingStringDelegate  {

   // here I get stuck, what to do?
    var gameScene : GameScene = GameScene()

     override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        gameScene.gamescene_transmissiondelegate = self
     }

     func didReceiveString(message:String) {
       print ("hi there", message)
     }

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to accomplish.  Generally one would be displayed and running at a time.  If you make an instance of `SecondScene` and display it, it'll make a `gameScene` and set itself as the delegate, but that `gameScene` is inactive based on what you've shown.

Comment: I am playing around with Multipeer Connectivity, right now I have a Scene where players can connect to each other. The connection is build in that scene and telemetry starts in that scene. Once the game is starting, the telemetry has to move with it to the new scene. If people have suggestions on how to do this differently, I am eager to hear :)

Comment: I moved my telemetry functions to a global class, from there I can delegate without issue.  Perhaps even better like it is now?

Answer (score 1):

I woudld do it with scene properties vs a global class

```
class ConnectionScene: SKScene {

    private var player1pos: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
    private var player2pos: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero

    ///some code in this scene sets player positions

    func startMultiplayerGame() {

        //this assumes your scene is setup in the editor not programmatically
        if let gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

            gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            gameScene.player1pos = player1pos
            gameScene.player2pos = player2pos

            self.view?.presentScene(multiplayerScene, transition: SKTransition.reveal(with: .down, duration: 1.0))
        }
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var player1pos: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var player2pos: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero

    override func sceneDidLoad() {

        //sceneDidLoad happens first
        super.sceneDidLoad()

        //do setup that doesn't require passed in variables in here

        //this isn't set from connectScene yet so won't have the values
        print("player1pos \(player1pos)")
        print("player2pos \(player2pos)")
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        //didMove happens last and already has the variables assigned

        //now do setup that requires these variables

        //this now has value from connectScene
        print("player1pos \(player1pos)")
        print("player2pos \(player2pos)")  
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks , it's a good suggestion, but I need to send over other information as well. I think I go ahead with my global 'telemetry' class and meanwhile I keep researching.